# why my app crashes when i want to make a movign background in android studio?

Tags: android

i am making a project in which i want to make a moving gradient background, like the background colour will change after a specific seconds. but when i run my code, my app crashes although there are no errors. here's my code:

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_list"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

mainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);

        AnimationDrawable animationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) linearLayout.getBackground();

        animationDrawable.setEnterFadeDuration(2500);
        animationDrawable.setExitFadeDuration(5000);

        animationDrawable.start();
}
}
```

all my gradient files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/play"
        android:duration="4000"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/play1"
        android:duration="4000"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/play2"
        android:duration="4000"/>
</animation-list>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#66ff66"
        android:endColor="#ff99cc"
        android:angle="225" />
</shape>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#003366"
        android:endColor="#66ffcc"
        android:angle="135" />
</shape>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#ffcc00"
        android:endColor="#ff99cc"
        android:angle="45" />
</shape>
```

thnx!! in advance.

Comment: kindly add your stack trace from logcat for better understanding of crash

Answer (score 0):

You have to change this line

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
```

to

```
CoordinatorLayout linearLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
```

your layout was wrong.

Comment: what does CoordinatorLayout means? sorry for asking but i am new to android studio. and when i run the code nothing happens.

Comment: Its your parent layout in xml file. It's one kind of layout like LinearLayout, RelativeLayout.

Comment: ok thnx!! but the colour does not change only.... any help?